# PushWoosh plugin: External repo not found in Phonegap Build (PGB)

Tags: phonegap-build, pushwoosh, phonegap-pushplugin

I am using PGB (PhonegapBuild) and added pushwoosh plugin 3.4.5, it runs perfect since the app build but since last night, my build failed everytime, even i have not make any changes in config.xml or pushwoosh code. I am getting this error

**Error - Plugin (or a specific plugin version) not found in external repo: com.pushwoosh.plugins.pushwoosh**

Any one can help

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like every time new version of the plugin is submitted, the old one disappears from plugins.cordova.io.

I'm not really sure how plugins.cordova.io works, doing search for pushwoosh plugin there displays version 3.4.9
http://plugins.cordova.io/#/search?search=pushwoosh

This is how you should add the plugin:
<gap:plugin name="com.pushwoosh.plugins.pushwoosh" source="plugins.cordova.io" />

Remove "version" attribute, it worked for me after.

Comment: thanks for your response but if i remove the version attr. then in future if they make changes then the plugin will automatically updated and need to update the changes in code.
Did you have the same issue?

Comment: You are correct. However I don't see any other way at the moment as plugins.cordova.io erases any previous version of the plugin. Effectively it means you have to be on the latest version of the plugin (thanks Phonegap!). 

P.S. I'll try not to break Pushwoosh plugin interface in the future versions :)